# Is it practical to do high-precision calculations with asm.js?

Tags: javascript, html, math, fractals, asm.js

I've been working on an HTML5 application that draws fractal images defined by iterating functions, such as the famous Mandelbrot fractal. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set

My understanding is that Javascript uses only a single data type for numbers, double-precision floating point.  Due to this limitation, I cannot make my program draw as precisely as I would like to be able to.  There are images and videos on the internet that represent fractal images so precise that they use hundreds of digits after the decimal point.  See here for an example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=foxD6ZQlnlU

I have heard of high-precision calculation libraries for Javascript, but the ones I have seen all use strings to represent numbers, which is incompatible with asm.js.

Is there a practical way to do high-precision calculations with asm.js?  How high?  I would say arbitrarily high.  The precision needs to be adjustable.

If I had to take a shot in the dark, I would guess that since asm.js does support integer arithmetic, I could somehow make it work by using arrays of integers to represent a large number of digits after the decimal point.  I could represent the digits as strings and have a small function to divide them up into arrays to be passed to asm.js code.

Comment: Yes, that could work.

Comment: I'd take a look at source code of Google Web Toolkit (GWT). They have to simulate much of Java SDK, maybe there is an implementation of BigDecimal which is compatible with asm.js. Just a thought - I don't know whether this helps...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a project,

## **[gmp.js](https://github.com/kripken/gmp.js)**

which appears to be a port of the [GNU Multiple-Precision Arithmetic Library](https://gmplib.org/) to JavaScript via [emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten), which uses asm.js as its default code-generation target; since gmp.js is written by the same author as emscripten, it would seem to be pretty legitimate.